# DailyMotion video says geo-restricted but API says no geoblocking. What is happening here?

Tags: dailymotion-api

DailyMotion video: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/kO0LNAXij6uFmerLQta states it is geo-restricted.

[image: https://imgur.com/dgF5vl8.jpg]

But in the API explorer there are no geoblocking entries.

[image]

What am I missing? If a video is geo restricted how do I determine that using the video id through the API?

Answer (score 1):

Your video is not geoblocked by your configuration.
The geoblock is due to the copyright content policy.

You can check our Copyright & content policies here: [Version en-us](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/en-us/categories/200290417-Copyright-Content-Policies) [Version fr](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/fr/categories/200290417-Politiques-de-contenu).
Please contact the support for any claim: [Contact form](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/fr/requests/new?ticket_form_id=136048#new-request)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If copyright content block, shouldn't the message say that instead of 'geo-restricted by owner' ? And more importantly, is there a way to determine copyright content block through the API?

Comment: We will update the message about the geo-restriction due to Copyright policiy. Unfortunatly you can't determine if your video is Copyrighted by the API, but you should have recieved an email informing you that the video is Copyrighted.

Comment: Thanks. It's not my video, I'm just using the API to determine if certain videos are still available. So this copyright block not showing in the API makes things problematic.